Using Nikon SB-910 as Commander and SB-600 as Slave with CLS
Am trying to extended the range of CLS by using SB-910 as on camera Commander on D71000/D810. However SB-910 fails to trigger the remote SB-600 slave flashes. The build-in popup flashes does trigger SB-600 slave flashes.
Here are the steps I followed:
Camera Settings:
Set camera flash mode to wireless commander. All the groups are set to TTL and channel to 1.
SB-910 (Commander, On Camera):
I have set the SB-910 as master by turning the dial to 'Master'.
On the SB-600 (Slave):
Set the remote slave and set the group to 'b' and channel '1'.

Does the SB-910 Master also enable B?

The SB910 needs to be set to master... see section D of the owner's manual.
